# Retaining objects in blocks

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, block

The following is my code using GCD to fetch data from the network and then pass it to a response block on the main queue.

```
+ (void)allData:(void(^)(NSArray*))responseBlock
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            __block NSArray *data = [[self all] retain]; // get data from network 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                responseBlock(data); // 2
            });
        });
}
```

The [[self all] retain] is to prevent the object from being released . But now the responseBlock has to release it . Is this the correct way ?

Comment: Why not say `[data release]` after the call to `responseBlock(data)`?

Comment: Also, why is `data` a `__block` variable to begin with?

Comment: well there seems to be a problem .(Sometimes though not consistently) i get a bad access if i dont retain data before switching to the main queue since it is an autoreleased object. I tried reading all the memory management guides and still dont knw what the right way is.

Comment: thanks ! it shudnt hv been block ... oh well .. but if it isnt block it will be auto retained right ?

Comment: So i just want to know if im correcting in saying that if i remove the __block specifier both the blocks (the enclosing and the response block) will auto retain the array and so i wont have any leak or bad accesses. I've taken care to avoid retain cycles in the block.

Comment: @eddardstark: `data` is captured by the inner block, so it will retain `data` when it is copied. `self` is captured by the outer block, so it will retain `self` when it is copied.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this

```
+ (void)allData:(void(^)(NSArray*))responseBlock
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            __block NSArray *data = [[self all] retain]; // get data from network 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                responseBlock(data); // 2
                [data release]; // you can release here
                data = nil;
            });
        });
}
```

or simply remove `__block`, the inner block (the one you pass to main queue) will retain/release `data` automatically and because `data` does not retaining anything else so I can't see any possible retain cycle here (since `self` here is a `Class`).

Comment: well once Kevin pointed it out to me i realized it was a mistake to make it __block . Your answer is also useful for when the inner variable has to be made as __block . thanks.